# Fisher's principle in humans

Tags: evolutionary-game-theory, sex-ratio

[Some research](https://psmag.com/environment/17-to-1-reproductive-success) suggests that men have historically had far less reproductive success than women, even given the approximately 1:1 sex ratio in humans. However, doesn't Fisher's principle suggest that the sex ratio should adjust to the point where neither sex has a reproductive advantage over the other? In this case, shouldn't the equilibrium sex ratio for humans have more females than males?

Comment: The duplicate used a cat example, but it's the same principle regardless of the species: just replace cat with human. Half the genetic material of each offspring comes from a male. It may be "riskier" to be male in a world where few males reproduce, but the payout is better for one that survives.

Comment: Welcome to Biology StackExchange! I am not an expert, but I think you might be misunderstanding the Fisher's principle. "_Fisher's principle states that natural selection favours an equal number of **male and female births** at the population level ..."_ [(source)](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsbl.2020.0620) and _"Fisher, in 1930, famously provided an explanation for why most animal species, including humans, **produce approximately equal numbers of males and females**."_ [(source)](http://zoo-web02.zoo.ox.ac.uk/group/west/pdf/West_13.pdf)

Comment: Ahh ok, I implicitly assumed the objective was on the extensive margin (i.e. whether one reproduced or not) as opposed to the intensive margin (number of descendants). Under risk neutrality and the latter objective, the 1:1 ratio makes sense.